# Как слушают сообщения WhatsApp или Telegram в Doze mode на Android?

Tags: android, websocket, android-asynctask, асинхронность

Есть задача, чтобы приложение на Android слушало websocket, но из Doze mode оно этого не делает.
Вроде как эту проблему решает Android WorkManager c его PeriodicWorkRequest. Раз в 15 минут приложению точно будет предоставлено окошко, чтобы проверить обновления.

Но приложения WhatsApp и Telegram явно доставляют сообщения, если не мгновенно, то очень быстро и Doze mode им не помеха. В документации указано, что сообщения от Firebase доставляются сразу же, даже если устройство находится в Doze mode.
Кто-нибудь знает как это у них реализовано? Через Firebase или какой-то другой инструмент (просьба назвать)?

С Firebase как-то сыкотно связываться с моим небольшим опытом, особенно после прочтения статьи как стартаперы угорели с Firebase на 72 000 долларов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase - принадлежит гуглу. Поэтому на них не распространяются правила, которым все остальные должны следовать. Введя эти правила, они лишили вас и все остальных делать то, что вы хотите. Засим единственный способ - использовать таки FCM. Он, в данный момент, бесплатный, так что денег вы потратить на него никак не сможете.

Comment: Меня не много напрягает эта страница с тарифами: https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=ru
Хотя напротив FCM действительно стоит - Free. Похоже я не вполне понимаю, что это за компонент.

Comment: Некоторые фичи Firebase платные, некоторые - бесплатные. Пуши (FCM - Firebase Cloud Message) - бесплатные. Если вы не будете использовать платный функционал - денег не потратите.

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, большое!

Comment: Работают пуши так: GMS приложение на девайсе держит постоянное сокет соединение с серверами гугла. Вы со своего сервера посылаете данные на сервера гугла, а они передают их в GMS, которые передают их уже вашему приложению.